# "Twoside" doesn't change the format of the table of contents, why?

Tags: formatting, typography

For my bachelor thesis I used the following document class:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,DIV=8,BCOR=5mm,twoside,pdftex,bibtotocnumbered]{scrreprt}
```

After the binding of the thesis I realized that the bigger margins are on the inside(on the binding site) and not on the outside like it should be. After I scrolled through I found the problem. The table of contents stays untouched by the twoside option. When you look at the PDF my two sides of the table of contents have the exact same outer margin and inner margin which leads to a complete reverse of the formatting, so that after the table of contents, the big margin is on the inside and the small one is on the outside. Now my question is, why twoside didn't change the orientation of the table of contents ? What is the mistake ?

I realized that there is one more mistake. Before the table of contents there are two pages which shouldn't be numbered but first page of the table of ontents
has page number 3 and the next page has number 1. My Code for this looks like this:
This ist the first page

```
\begin{titlepage}
...
\end{titlepage}
```

Then comes the second page

```
thispagestyle{empty}
...
```

After that comes the TOC

```
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

After this my real thesis begins:

```
\chapter{Beginning}
...
```

Comment: what is the page number of your table of contents (it would be easier to comment if you provided an example)

Comment: Oh, man, there is one more mistake. The first page of the table of contents has the page number 3 and the second page number 1... Before the table of contents there are two pages which souldn't be numbered.

Comment: the page numbering of the front matter is due to code that you have not shown, marking up the frontmatter. If you provide a small complete document that does not work as you expect then someone will debug, otherwise impossible to guess how unseen code is making unseen output.

Comment: If the first page of the ToC has number 3 and the second 1, then both are odd pages as far as LaTeX is concerned, so you'd expect the same margin. Obviously this shouldn't be happening. This suggests some code is seriously messing with your page numbering. The code shown so far does not look like it would be responsible for that. I'm afraid you will have to share a compilable example document with us that reproduces the odd behaviour with as little code as possible (an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)

Comment: your just added code lines are incorrect and forcing the last page of the table of contents to be 1, if you show more code, we will be able to fix more bugs but a complete document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` is easiest to comment on.

Comment: `\tableofcontents\setcounter{page}{1}` looks a bit wrong as it will make the *last* page of the ToC page 1. I have a hunch what a solution would look like, but I would not like to share it without having seen the context (a proper MWE), because the 'best' solution depends on stuff you have not shown us so far.

Comment: one simple fix would be to put `\cleardoublepage` before resetting the counter but impossible to say what else might be needed

Comment: the page numbers both being odd of course explains why they had the same layout.

Comment: I added some more details.

Comment: @Sen90 still not the requested test file so still leaves people guessing, but no matter I posted an answer anyway now.

Comment: Off topic: Option `bibtotocnumbered` is  obsolete. Replace it by `bibliography=totocnumbered` or `toc=bibliographynumbered`.

Answer (score 1):

In code shown after the original posting, you have

```
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

This forces the page number at that point to be 1, but this is most likely the final page of the table of contents so apparently in your case the two pages of the table of contents had numbers 3 and 1 so both had the odd side page layout.

You could use

```
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

so that the setting to 1 happens on the page after the table of contents, although normally when you reset the page number you also reset the style, for example having lower case Roman for the front matter and Arabic for the main matter.  the `\pagenumbering` command does both these things, resetting the counter style and resetting the value to 1 so

```
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

Comment: I think the following order solved it: First \cleardoublepage then \setcounter{page}{1} and then \tableofcontents

Comment: @Sen90 well that removes the bug of changing the page number midway through the toc but traditionally the table of contents counts as front matter and you would restart the main page number sequence at 1 at the start of the main matter, so after that as I showed, but it's your document.

Comment: If I want the numbering of the pages to start with the TOC, is this the right way to do it ? When I use your order than the table of contents has the numbers 3 and 4 and then starts with 1.

Comment: @Sen90 yes.....

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem with the following code:

Instead of

```
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

I have written

```
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\tableofcontents
```

With that the numbering begins with the TOC, as I wanted and also solves the problem with the side margins.